# Gear icon missing from login screen

Tags: unity, login, desktop-environments

I'm looking at the login prompt on an Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. I should be seeing - so I've been told - a gear icon in the corner of the highlighted rectangle around the username, which would allow me to change desktop environments, e.g.:

[image]

Yet - it's missing. I know I have more than one desktop environment installed (LXDE and Unity). Why is it missing, and how can I get it back? (I have root on this machine but I'm not the one who had set it up.)